# spring data neo4j Embedded : Connect to localhost:7474 failed: Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

Having this configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.mydb.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer( "http://localhost:7474" );
    }       
    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( new File("./mydb.db") )
                .setConfig( ServerSettings.auth_enabled, Boolean.FALSE.toString() )             
                .newGraphDatabase();

    }    
    @Bean
    @Override
    @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }        
    @Bean
    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.mydb.model");
    }    
}
```

I have 2 errors :

1_ I can't keep the Session in scope "session"

2_ I have the exception : Connect to localhost:7474 failed: Connection refused:

The server is Embedded, it should start without instaling any server on my local machine ?

```
Spring-boot 1.3.0 (Last) and 
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of SDN are you using?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by SDN, but i update my question with the used versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 4.0 of Spring Data for Neo4j doesn't support embedded version of Neo4j.

You need to install Neo4j on your local machine.

"SDN 4.1 will support embedded version." @Luanne

Comment: Is it definitive, i choose Neo4j because it can be used as Embeded Server, otherwise i could go to MongoDb or Cassandra ...?

Comment: And its not mentioned here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/ !!

Comment: SDN 4.0.0.RELEASE does not support neo4j embedded. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_neo4jserver_bean refers only to a remote server. SDN 4.1 will support embedded but it hasn't been released yet